# Log4Net roll based on date and size

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

hi i am using rolling file appender of log4net for logging ,
my requirement is file should get roll based on size and date . 
but currently file is only rolling based on date , if file size is corssing the limit i set its deleting all log .
this is my configuration -

```
   <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <file value=""/>
      <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
        <levelMax value="ERROR"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
```

my server side code -

```
var fileAppender = LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().OfType<RollingFileAppender>().FirstOrDefault(fa => fa.Name == "RollingLogFileAppender");
if (fileAppender != null)
{
    fileAppender.File = Path.Combine(Constants._debugFilesPath + "\\Log-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".txt");
    fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
}
```

also after size is exceeding the limit  file looks like this - 
[image]

any suggestion what i have to change in configuration to get correct log after size exceed .
thanks

Comment: Did you found how to do it? I have the same issue

Comment: no , i just increased file size in config file